# What number of storage groups should be set for Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Are there any limit of setting the number of storage groups in Apache IoTDB? I read the user guide and it said that increasing the number of storage groups can improve the database performance, but I also saw the possible problems of setting too many storage groups. I want to know what are the choices of storage groups in Apache IoTDB, and what settings can IoTDB support to ensure performance for small number of storage groups?

Answer (score 0):

Now it is recommended to set up only one storage group in Apache IoTDB. If you are worrying about concurrency issues, `region` in IoTDB can be automatically expanded in one database settings to improve concurrency from Version 1.X and above.